# In doubt of range of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that: $$f(x)=x^2+6 ;; -1\leq x\leq 2$$

My attempt:

When $x=-1, f(x)=7$

When $x=2, f(x)=11$

So the range of $f(x)$ is $7\leq f(x) \leq 11$

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Since $f(x) = x^2+6$ it can never be lower than 6 since $x^2$ is non-negative. $f(x)$ = 6 only if $x^2 = 0 \iff x = 0$ and $0$ is contained in the interval $[-1;2]$ so the lowest value $f$ can take is $6$. For the highest value you need to consider where in the given interval $x^2$ reaches its greatest value and that is at $x=2$ where $x^2 = 4$ so $f(2) = 2^2 + 6 = 4+6 = 10.$ Therefore the range is 
$$
6\leq f(x) \leq 10, ~~ x\in [-1;2].
$$

Answer (score 0):

No this is used when the function is decreasing or increasing in the given

interval.

Look at the graph of $f(x)=1 / x^2$ in the interval $[-1 , 1 ]$ . $f(1)=1$ and $f(-1)=1$

Dose it correct to say $1 \lt 1 / x^2 \lt 1$  ?

You see this way is not correct for a function other than a decreasing or

increasing.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not. The extremity of the function is at $0$. (The derivative of the function equals $0$ at $0$.) The value is $6$ at the extremity. Also, the value of the function at $2$ is $10$. So the range is $[6,10].$

Illustration:

[image]